# The file path of the file upload in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

In an *html* file, I have:

```
<form action="save.php" method="post" >
<input type="file" name="file" id="file`enter code here`" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Save" />
```

So I need the path of the uploaded file to the **save.php** page, please guide me.

Comment: you can access file detail using $_FILES.

Comment: do you mean `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`?

Comment: yes , after that you have to pass that to `move_uploaded_file()`

Answer (score 1):

The file won't be upload until you write PHP code in `save.php` file.

You will get values of selected file in `$_FILES` after submitting form data. Please use `move_uploaded_file()` PHP function to upload file.

Comment: Hi Manish, thanks for your help. I need the current path file, not new location. Something like that "document.getElementById("file").value;" in Ajax but I haven't any idea haw can I use it in save.php file.

Comment: I try  this in php file but it didn't work also:                                          $dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTML('C:\wamp64\www\opencaster\upload.html');
$elm = $dochtml->getElementById("file").value;